# Create many arrays in one line

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to do something like the following

```
e = []
m = []
p = []
t = []
...and so on for about 10 different arrays
```

Is there a way to create all these arrays on one line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it using the following:

```
e,m,p,t... = Array.new(10) { [] }
```

It turns out

```
[[]]*10
```

is not the right way to go, `[[]]*10` is for repetition and is just repeating the same object `[]` 10 times, so all the variables would end up getting assigned to the same object.

Comment: The first solution is good (though you can just do `Array.new(10) { [] }`). However, your second solution has a gotcha. If one of the variables gets modified (eg `e << "foo"`), then `m`,`p`,`t` etc. get modified as well.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm Yea that's how I started actually, I thought why not just [] instead of Array.new within the block, and then went on to trying to remove the first Array.new as well. But this is weird! I just confirmed what you said, can you perhaps explain why that is the case ?

Comment: @Dhruva: It's the same array referred to 10 times, rather than 10 distinct arrays. You can find that out by calling `object_id` on the object.

Comment: @Dhruva: I had a look at the RDoc, and it doesn't make explicitly clear the danger of `[[]]*10` (or `Array.new(10, [])`).

Comment: @Andrew Grimm that is really strange, I am checking with guys @ irc

Comment: This behaviour is explicitly described: http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Array:initialize

Answer (score 6):

Like multiple variable declaration in one line `a1, a2, a3 = 3, 10, 4`

```
e, m, p, t ... = [], [], [], [] ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm curious at what are those 10 different arrays, because I would suspect they shouldn't be 10 different variables but just one. You don't give any context, so I can only guess, something like the following might better:

```
whatever = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
whatever[:e] # => []
whatever[:m] << 42
whatever[:m] # => [42]
# etc...
```

Otherwise, as zomboid wrote:

```
e, m, p, t ... = [], [], [], [] ...
```

Comment: Interesting point! They are actually 10 different variables in this case because they are used for completely separate purposes. Thanks for that alternative approach. +1

Answer (score 5):

What all fails

```
>  p, q, r = v = Array.new(3, [])
 => [[], [], []] 
>  v.map(&:object_id)
 => [70155104393020, 70155104393020, 70155104393020] 
>  p = q = r = []
 => [] 
>  [p, q, r].map(&:object_id)
 => [70155104367380, 70155104367380, 70155104367380]
```

What works

```
>  p, q, r = v = Array.new(3){ [] }
 => [[], [], []] 
>  v.map(&:object_id)
 => [70155104731780, 70155104731760, 70155104731740]
```